# Google App Engine: This operation is not possible because no App Engine application was found for this project

Tags: python, cloud, google, google-app-engine

I'm trying to help a friend deploy a simple python app in google app engine (the free account). It seems as if his project could be corrupt?

The project is:

> Project ID sgvfr-riprunner

When I enter the google app engine section from the developers console I immediately get this:

This operation is not possible because no App Engine application was found for this project.

When I try to deploy via command line using the sdk I get:

```
linuxbox:~/sgvfr$ ../google_appengine/appcfg.py -A sgvfr-riprunner update email-webhook/app.yaml
10:18 PM Application: sgvfr-riprunner; version: 1
10:18 PM Host: appengine.google.com
10:18 PM 
Starting update of app: sgvfr-riprunner, version: 1
10:18 PM Getting current resource limits.
10:18 PM Scanning files on local disk.
Error 404: --- begin server output ---
This application does not exist (app_id=u'sgvfr-riprunner').
--- end server output ---
```

Any ideas what I can do? Am I forever in limbo?

Comment: It look like `sgvfr-riprunner` isn't defined in `appcfg.py` or `appcfg.py` path is incorrect

Comment: the files are defined properly, changing the yaml to another application id for another user works fine. Only not for this current user.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the Developers Console and then 'Manage all projects' (under 'Select a project' or the current project name at the top right) and make sure that project is actually active, and not in some other state. If you are just missing the App Engine section but everything else is fine, you will likely need to delete the project and create a new one.